# Copy-Item parse items

Tags: powershell

I want to copy all the items inside one folder, to other location, in a recursive way, but I also want to rename the files ended with "release.php" to ".php", and replace old ".php" files with these files, is there a way I can process each file Copy-Item sees? So I can rename it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try something like ?

```
PS>ls c:\temp -recurse |
      ForEach-Object {
      if($_.FullName -match "relase.php"){
         Rename-Item $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.baseName).php" -whatif;
         move-item "$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.Basename).php" $destination -whatif
      }
      else{
         move-item $_.Fullname $detination -whatif
      }
```